# How to connect WIFI using ssid and password in android Q?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-10.0

i want to connect to a wifi network using SSID and Password in android Q, below is my code for connect.

```
  private void connect(String ssid,String password){
       WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder builder = new WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder();
       builder.setSsid(ssid);
       builder.setWpa2Passphrase(password);

       WifiNetworkSpecifier wifiNetworkSpecifier = builder.build();

       NetworkRequest.Builder networkRequestBuilder = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
       networkRequestBuilder.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI);
       networkRequestBuilder.setNetworkSpecifier(wifiNetworkSpecifier);

       NetworkRequest networkRequest = networkRequestBuilder.build();
       cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

       networkCallback = new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback(){
           @Override
           public void onAvailable(@NonNull Network network) {
               super.onAvailable(network);
               Log.d(TAG, "onAvailable: "+network);
               cm.bindProcessToNetwork(network);
           }
       };
       cm.requestNetwork(networkRequest, networkCallback);
   }
```

and add following permission in manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

but till now i got bellow error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: com.a.wifidemoproject was not granted  either of these permissions: android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE, android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS.
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2074)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2042)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1990)
    at android.net.IConnectivityManager$Stub$Proxy.requestNetwork(IConnectivityManager.java:3494)
    at android.net.ConnectivityManager.sendRequestForNetwork(ConnectivityManager.java:3562)
    at android.net.ConnectivityManager.requestNetwork(ConnectivityManager.java:3594)
    at android.net.ConnectivityManager.requestNetwork(ConnectivityManager.java:3670)
    at android.net.ConnectivityManager.requestNetwork(ConnectivityManager.java:3631)
```

How to give `android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE, android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS`.
How to solve this problem and succfully connect to a wifi network in andoid Q.

Comment: Well, declare these permissions in your manifest. (which were mentioned in the exception)

Comment: i already declare the permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

Comment: Declare those permissions explicitly in manifest.

Comment: Like this: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS">`

Comment: thanks <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"> work  fine

Comment: @CoderCharmander please post your comment as an answer, so OP can accept it. This will help users in the future to recognize the correct answer right away. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just do what the exception says: declare the permissions in the manifest file like this:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```